# How to convert column list to data frame in R

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm scraping voting history data from pdfs.  Names are separated by spaces in single variable.  Want to change data frame so there is a separate column for the names

The names were separated and whitespace eliminated.  It produced a list of varying lengths--depending on who voted for it--in a new column in the data frame. Also, experimented with the `separate` function in the `dplyr` package.

```
#data.frame as is
bill <- c("HB1", "HB2")
names <- c("a    b", "a")
df.0 <- data.frame(bill = bill, names = names, stringsAsFactors = F)
df.0

#data.frame desired
bill <- c("HB1", "HB1", "HB2")
names <- c("a", "b", "a")
df.1 <- data.frame(bill = bill, names = names, stringsAsFactors = F)
df.1
```

Comment: Have you tried `strsplit(names, "\\s+")`?

Comment: Yes, it was generating a list as expected.  G. Grothendiek's response was the simplest solution. See below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) tidyr::separate_rows** Try `separate_rows` in tidyr:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df.0 %>% separate_rows(names)
```

giving:

```
  bill names
1  HB1     a
2  HB1     b
3  HB2     a
```

**1a) tidyr::unnest** A different tidyr solution can be fashioned from `strsplit` and `unnest`:

```
df.0 %>%
  mutate(names = strsplit(names, "\\s+")) %>%
  unnest
```

giving:

```
  bill names
1  HB1     a
2  HB1     b
3  HB2     a
```

**2) stack/strsplit**  This alternative uses no packages.  Here we use `strsplit` to split `names` into a list of character vectors.  Add `bill` names to that and use `stack` to conert that back to a data.frame.  `stack` will give it hard coded names so use `setNames` to set the names back.

```
setNames(with(df.0, stack(setNames(strsplit(names, "\\s+"), bill)))[2:1], names(df.0))
```

giving:

```
  bill names
1  HB1     a
2  HB1     b
3  HB2     a
```

Answer (score 3):

Try out:

```
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df.0, names)

# output
  bill names
1  HB1     a
2  HB1     b
3  HB2     a
```